# Updating a State List

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have declared a empty list in my state to be used to hold names a groups.  When I refresh the screen I make a api call and get a list of groups this member is apart of.  I am having trouble setting this list of names I get from the API to the state.  It currently takes a list of size 3 and just puts the entire array as one string instead of setting it as an array of values.

```
var objArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groups.data.data.getUser.groups));
    console.log(objArray);

    //These are the string arrays that need to be set to the state to update the card
    let names = objArray.map(({ name })=> name);
    console.log('Names: ' + names.length); //This is 3

    this.setState({ groupNames: [`${names}`] });

    console.log(this.state.groupNames.length);//This outputs 1 when it should be 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
this.setState({ groupNames: names});
```

you were putting the names array in a new array by using `[names]` instead of simply `names`, this new array only has one child: the names array (as a string), thus the length is returning 1 instead of 3

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I thought it should be easy like this but for some reason I could not find a straight forward answer like this online.

Comment: glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just assign names to groupNames as below

this.setState({ groupNames: names });

template literals created using ` converts your array to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value to a new array in this statement. That's why it is showing the length 1.

```
this.setState({ groupNames: [`${names}`] });  // It is wrong
```

It should be like that

```
this.setState({ groupNames: names });
```